# Issues with send_file for pdf file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdftk

I am using pdftk for generating PDF. After generating it, I want to open that PDF file in my browser. Here is code that I have used for pdf open in browser:

```
send_file(params[:myfile], :filename => "test.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
```

In this, **params[:myfile]** is path of the PDF file where it is stored.

My issue is when I execute this code, it opens file in new window with table structure but is not showing any content in that PDF file

I dont want to open the PDF as an attachment.

Please give your positive suggestion.

Comment: I'm using prawn with that same structure of code. And there is no problem. I think it's not the source of problem. Have you analyse more of your case?

Comment: [kolonel peteruk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1272973/kolonel-peteruk), i have analysed a lot on this. i am able to get pdf in attachment(:disposition => 'attachment') perfectly but its is not showing correctly in browser window(:disposition => 'inline')

Comment: Have you try with other browser(s)? Have you analyze perhaps there is some of your PDF layout, or perhaps how PDFTK render to browser?

Comment: I have tried this with crome and firefox. In both case i am getting the same issue. If you want then i can post my code here for your better understanding

Comment: It's okay, perhaps another coder would came and can help you more.